# mysql matching select like hashtags, without fulltext

Tags: mysql, regex

I can't fulltext setting ft_min_word_len because i use web-hosting.

**DB Field**
hashtag - varchar(256) / utf8_general_ci

**DB input value example**
| #abc |
| #abc #123 |
| #123 |
| #abc #123 #abcd |
| #1234 |
| #12345 |

**I want to search '#123' result**

| #abc #123 |
| #123 |
| #abc #123 #abcd |

**PHP**

```
$word = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['word']);
mysqli_query($mysqli, "... where (p.hashtag REGEXP '^(.*?(\\\b$word\\\b)[^$]*)$' ) ... ");
```

I want to more than systax.

> add comment
>   **DB Input value more detail**
>
>   id | title | descript | hastag      | viewCnt ...
>   1  | text1 | text0001 | #123        |    0   
>   2  | text2 | text0002 | #123 #abc   |    0   
>   3  | text3 | text0003 | #12345      |    0   
>   ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should fix your data structure to have a table with one row per hash tag value and id in the table you are using.

But in any case, you can do what you want using `like`:

```
select hashtag
from db
where concat(hashtag, '#') like concat('%', $search, '#%');
```

Comment: @Integral . . . Oops.  I left out the wildcards.

Comment: @Integral . . . Not with this data structure.  You can improve performance with the SQLish data structure, with only one value in the column.

Comment: gratitude for your great reply!

Comment: @GordonLinoff Why do you do this? `concat(hashtag, '#')`

Comment: @MarlonAbeykoon . . . To be sure that #abc does not match #abcd.